# How to calculate summation of different columns value with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a dataset with thousands of records. I need to calculate the sum of values for each day and save it to a separate column based on two conditional statement of col3 and col4. The loop count for each day has been stored in col2.

```
condition 1: 
if col3< col4 take col4 value for summation.
condition 2:
if col3 >= col4 take col3 value for summation.
```

Test Dataset:

```
id    col2    col3    col4    timestamp
0      3        0       50       1-12-2018
1      3        40      35       1-12-2018
2      3        30      30       1-12-2018
3      2        23      14       2-12-2018
4      2        33      33       2-12-2018
5      1        25      50       3-12-2018
```

Now I need to find the summation as per the above conditions and calculate probability from it.
The Desired output is :

```
id    col2    col3    col4       timestamp    sum    P
0      3        0       50       1-12-2018    120   50/120
1      3        40      35       1-12-2018    120   40/120
2      3        30      30       1-12-2018    120   30/120
3      2        23      44       2-12-2018    77    23/77 
4      2        33      33       2-12-2018    77    33/77
5      1        25      50       3-12-2018    50    50/50
```

So far with python I have done this, which only takes summation of either col3 or col4. But, I am confused how to calculate the summation based on the conditions I mentioned above and also calculate the probability to produce desired output:

```
import csv 
fin = open("tx.in.txt","r")
list_id = {}
for line in fin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split()
    if('value' not in f):
        try:
            list_id[f[4]]+=int(f[2])
        except:
            list_id[f[4]]=int(f[2])
fin.close()
for k,v in list_txid.items():
    print("{0}\t{1:d}".format(k, v))
```

P.S : I can't install/use pandas library for limited access to the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use pandas for your use case

Comment: Can you post your CSV

Comment: @Rakesh, sorry I just updated the question, can't use pandas. Please use the test data for suggesting solution. thanks

Comment: you say you can't use pandas, but can you use numpy?

Comment: @DavidL, yes I can. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `csv module`.

```
import csv
res = []
with open(r"tx.in.txt", "r") as infile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=';')     #Read CSV as a dictionary.
    for i in r:
        val = i
        if int(val["col3"]) < int(val["col4"]):
            val["sum"] = int(val["col4"])
        elif int(val["col3"]) >= int(val["col4"]):
            val["sum"] = int(val["col3"])
        else: 
            val["sum"] = 0

        res.append(val)

print(res)
```

Comment: Please check the desired output and modify the code accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest reading in all of the data at once

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open('tx.in.txt','r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, sep=sep)
    headers = next(reader,None)
    datalist = [[row[0],row[1],int(row[2]),int(row[3]),row[4]] for row in reader]
```

Then, get an extra array that just contains the higher of col3 and col4, and list of timestamps

```
highs = np.array([max(row[2],row[3]) for row in datalist])
times = [row[-1] for row in datalist]
```

get indices for each unique timestamp

```
time_inds = {time:[ind for ind, tim in enumerate(times) if tim==time] for time in set(times)}
```

create an array of sum values

```
sum_vals = np.zeros(highs.size,dtype=int)
for time, inds in time_inds.items():
    sum_vals[inds] = np.sum(highs[inds])
```

Finally, add the new columns to the data

```
headers += ['sum', 'P']
for data, sum_val, high in zip(datalist, sum_vals, highs):
    data += [sum_val, '%d/%d' % (high, sum_val)]
```

finally, convert to a dictionary:

```
list_txid = {head:values for head, values in zip(headers, list(map(list, zip(*datalist))))}
```

although if you know how to read in a csv file as a dict off the bat, this could be made simpler. I focused on handling the getting the sums by row part

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\...\sum_prb1.py", line 14, in <module>
    data.append(sum_val, '%d/%d' % (high, sum_val))
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: fixed it. should have been data += [sum_val, '%d/%d' % (high, sum_val)]. Sorry, couldn't test code without example file

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mithu\workspace\Data_struct\sum_prb1.py", line 17, in <module>
    list_txid = {head:values for head, values in zip(headers, list(map(list, zip(*data))))}
TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration

Comment: sorry, *data should have been *datalist

Comment: Great, thanks, now there are no errors, but how to export the desired output to a file?

Comment: Didn't realize you need to save it to a file. In that case datalist=['\t'.join(list(map(str,data))) for data in datalist] would convert datalist into an easy to write format

with open(filename,'w') as w:
    w.write('\t'.join(headers)+'\n'+'\t'.join(datalist))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168710/discussion-between-rubz-and-david-l).

Answer (score 1):

using no modules, this may not be the fastest method though:

```
with open(r"tx.in.txt", "r") as infile:
    txt=infile.readlines()

data=[line.split() for line in txt[1:]]

idx=0
while idx<len(data):
    loop=int(data[idx][1])
    if idx+loop>len(data):
        print("Out of bounds!")
        break
    lmax=[]
    for i in range(loop):
        c3,c4=[int(d) for d in data[idx+i][2:4]]
        lmax.append(c3 if c3>=c4 else c4)
    for i in range(loop):
        data[idx+i].append(str(sum(lmax)))
        data[idx+i].append("{}/{}".format(lmax[i],sum(lmax)))

    idx+=loop
print ("id      col2    col3    col4    timestamp   sum     P")
for dat in data:
    print("{d[0]:8s}{d[1]:8s}{d[2]:8s}{d[3]:8s}{d[4]:12s}{d[5]:8s}{d[6]:8s}".format(d=dat))
```

Comment: Thanks, But did you forgot the code for the final printed output?

Comment: sorry, i've edited my answer to include the printed output

Comment: Great, thanks, But only one issue, can the probability column values be displayed in floating results?

Comment: Instead of a fraction? Of course. Instead of `data[idx+i].append("{}/{}".format(lmax[i],sum(lmax)))` you can write `data[idx+i].append("{:8.3f}".format(lmax[i]/sum(lmax)))`. If you are using python 2.7, you may want to convert one of the members of the fraction into a float beforehand, i.e. `float(lmax[i])/sum(lmax)`.

Comment: The code is not working on my actual data, each value of the col3 and col4  are very large(e.g 5000000000). The summations are not correct and The result of P as well. By the way,  my server has python 2.7.5.

Comment: The last line  of my answer contains the width information of the output. By changing the number in front of the "s",e.g.frim 8 to 18,  you can adjust.

Comment: 0       3       0       50      1-12-2018   120        0.000
1       3       40      35      1-12-2018   120        0.000
     2       3       30      30      1-12-2018   120        0.000
     3       2       23      14      2-12-2018   56         0.000
     4       2       33      33      2-12-2018   56         0.000
     5       1       25      50      3-12-2018   50         1.000                     
    You can  see the 7th column of probability showing wrong answers.

Comment: The division calculating the probability is using integer division.
you can solve this by converting the elements of lmax to float either at assignment `(lmax.append(float(c3 if c3>c4 else c4)))` or at calculation as i suggested above.

Comment: Awesome! it worked again! is it possible to assign the (lmax[i])/sum(lmax) calculation part as  a variable and do another 2-3 math operation like taking log and store it to one more column?

Comment: of course. within the loop, you can assign further lists, and append them to the data[idx+i] list freely. Don't forget to expant the output string by d[7] and so on later. Either convert them to string at calculation, when appending to the data or keep in mind the formating rules applied at output! for more information on formatting to string, [have a look at this](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: My data is having many long loops like 100000 and the total number of lines in the data file is very large (100000000), is there any way to expedite the processing time?

Comment: For data of that size, the only thing i can recommend is using a module capable of handling huge arrays or databases like panda or numpy, though that would require a different approach in a seperate answer.